# Hibernate computer with a timeout from command line on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, hibernate

I am trying to hibernate my computer from the command. I was using `shutdown /s /t 20` to shutdown the the computer. I change /s to /h to hibernate and now it just returns the usage text as if it doesn't recognise what I have entered.
In this is does say

```
/h         Hibernate the local computer.
```

Is there something else that I need to use with /h to get it to hibernate?

Comment: But in this case (the case that you use waitfor or something like that) you can't abort the scheduled hibernation....

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I don't believe you can set a time for hibernation, unfortunately.

Try:

```
ping -n 20 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1 && shutdown /h /f
```

The `ping` is a hackish way of delaying the action. `-n 20` should wait for 20 seconds.

(the double `&&` will allow you to do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel the operation, but if you use a simple `&` then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will only break the timer and then continue to shut down)

Comment: haha, +1 for this nice "sleep" replacement :) i wrote my own .exe to do this, but .. hehahahahr.

Comment: Why we can't set time for hibernate? it wouldn't difficult for windows developers to allow this feature. but why they didn't? O.o

Comment: Nice but && not working in powershell

Comment: Note: the `> NUL 2>&1` part will prevent any output from the `ping` (for more see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30814001/8740349)).

Answer (score 49):

You could also consider using "timeout" or "waitfor" commands in a similar manner.

```
timeout /t 20 /NOBREAK > NUL && shutdown /h
```

or

```
waitfor NUL /t 20 || shutdown /h
```

More here: [How do I make a batch file wait / sleep for some seconds?](https://superuser.com/questions/48231/windows-7-bat-file-wait-sleep)

Comment: Both options works, but **the first is better**. If you want to cancel the command via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the first option will be canceled, but the second will receive a `false` in the first condition and jump to `shutdown` command directly.

Comment: The second example can be made better by using `waitfor NUL /t 20 && shutdown /h` instead.

Answer (score 13):

I use the following:

```
sleep 20 && shutdown /h /f
```

Or this if I want it off at a certain time:

```
At 22:30 shutdown /h /f
```

Comment: i hsve tried the command `At 22:30 shutdown /h /f`in cmd prompt , i got a message like access denied but i'm the admin in my pc. awaiting for your respose

Comment: I believe in Windows 10 they've changed the permissions required to use 'at'. It's only intended for system jobs and you have to be SYSTEM account in order to execute it. Yes, SYSTEM is more privileged that admin accounts (locally) and yes, there is a way to get a command prompt under the SYSTEM account.

Answer (score 10):

Of course you can set TIME for hibernation.

If you really want to hibernate your computer after a specific time, all you need to do is to enter this command below into the `cmd`. i.e:

```
timeout /t 36000 /nobreak && shutdown /h
```

Now the computer will start to count down from 36000 to 0 before it will hibernate. But you should note that you can change 36000 into any number of seconds that suits you.

Answer (score 9):

I think that it complains about time. Just put `shutdown /h` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have cygwin it's very simple: `sleep 45m && shutdown /h`

You can instruct `sleep` in minutes, hours, seconds and even days. Check out [this answer about `sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21621163/1714997).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the Windows Task Scheduler? If you have the script you can set it to run at a certain time - this should answer the time delay question.

Answer (score 2):

i always use this:

> shutdown -h

Comment: It doesn’t matter, you can’t time a hibernation (for some reason).

Comment: @Synetech It wouldn't difficult for windows developers to allow this feature. but why they didn't? O.o

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for timed hibernate for long time. Finally I made the following solution:

Create a `bat` file as below:

`timeout /t %1 /nobreak && shutdown /h`

Suppose it is saved in `C:\hibernate.bat`

Then open `Run` command (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>) and run the `bat` file with the timeout seconds as below:

`C:\hibernate.bat [timeout]`

Comment: The best solution IMHO. It's not hackish (like using `ping`, or redirecting `timeout` to `NUL`), it's practical.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PowerShell or have the Windows terminal as your default command-line interface then this is the only solution that has worked for me:

```
sleep 30 | shutdown /h /f
```

Of course you can change 30 to whatever amount of seconds you would like.

Comment: Could you explain the need for /f parameter? Just `sleep 30 | shutdown /h` worked fine for me. Also, hibernation needs to be enabled, in order for this command to work.

Comment: Update: now it hibernates instantly when using the `|` pipeline operator (PowerShell 7), but works correctly using the `&&` pipeline operator: `sleep 30 && shutdown /h`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBScript that will prompt for the number of seconds before hibernation:

```
Dim intSeconds,wshShell
intSeconds = InputBox("Enter number of seconds to wait","Hibernate timer")
Wscript.Sleep intSeconds
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "shutdown.exe -h -f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making multiple batch files, each with different number of seconds to wait, create and use the `hibernate-later.bat` file, which asks you when exactly you want to hibernate.

### Example

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo ===
:question
set "answer=0"
set /p answer="Hibernate after how many minutes? "
cls

rem Validate.
echo %answer%| findstr /r "^[1-9][0-9]*$">nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
    echo Counting...
) else (
    echo Invalid number.
    goto :question
)

set /A timeout=%answer% * 60
timeout /t !timeout! /nobreak

shutdown /h /f
pause
```

> **Note** that closing the Window cancels hibernate (for me at least), which is useful if you reconsider and decide to change the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution proposed by Radko Dinev for some time. However, converting the number of hours and minutes into seconds every time started to bother me. That's why I decided to write the program myself. I would like to leave here a link to such a program that I authored. Maybe it will be useful to someone who will be looking for a similar solution in the future. The program is free, I do not receive any benefits for downloading and using it.
You don't have to convert minutes and hours to seconds. It is also possible to turn off the monitor earlier. [hibernationdelayer](https://github.com/tytan15/HibernationDelayer/releases)

Comment: Please read the help on self promotion.  And teh question asked for a command line solution.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `/` use `-`.

Use the below command in the CMD as admin priv and test

```
shutdown -h
```