# Sleeping a computer via batch file in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sleep, batch-file

I want to make a batch file that will sleep my computer after a period of time.

The closest thing I have found is placing it in standby, but seems to work differently than the sleep button on my keyboard (longer bootup, doesn't wake on mouse click). Any ideas? Would it be easier in Python or C#?

The less then ideal technique mentioned above is calling this in the cmd prompt:

```
Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```

Comment: Just add a countdown part into the .bat and execute this after that.

Comment: looks like duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/83437/hibernate-computer-from-command-line-on-windows-7

Comment: Hibernation is totally diff, but yeah thats the correct solution I guess.

Comment: I believe the rundll thing is the same as hibernation.  With sleep, you click the mouse and your login screen is there in a couple seconds... hibernation has to recheck the bios, harddrives, and transfer the saved state from the harddrive to ram and then boot windows.  The only drawback to sleep is if you lose power and the saved state stored in ram is lost (and older pcs actually leave more components on like PSU and fans).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Simply command

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState
```

Does system **hibernate**, but if you write this:

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

And **turn off** hibernation with command:

```
powercfg -hibernate off
```

Now your system will go asleep, and will wake up on mouse move if selected a device for it (scroll down to learn how).

Batch a timer:

```
timeout /t 1200
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

Where **1200** is seconds, which mean after 20 minutes batch will run sleep command.

Optionally you can prevent canceling countdown (if you press any key in batch window):

```
timeout /t 1200 /nobreak
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

Little HOWTO about waking up with mouse:

**Go to:** *Start -> Control Panel -> Mouse.*

[image]

In the Mouse **Properties** window, click on the **Hardware** tab and select your mouse from the list of devices. Normally, there will only be one mouse listed here but that will depend on the hardware you have connected to your computer. When you have selected your mouse from the list, click the **Properties** button.

[image]

Now in the **Properties** window for your mouse, click on the **Change Settings** button on the **General** tab.

[image]

In the window that opens, click the **Power Management** tab and check the option titled **Allow This Device to Wake The Computer**. Click the **OK** button on this window and click the **OK** button on the **Mouse Properties** windows that is still open.
From now on, you can wake up Windows 7 from sleep mode by clicking a mouse button or moving the mouse around.

[image]

Comment: wow man, you really like answering questions :)

Answer (score 2):

```
shutdown /h
```

will hibernate the computer (not sure about suspend though).

Answer (score 2):

Working Solution!
I had to use the `PsShutdown` utility to allow proper sleeping (primary issue is `SetSuspendState` does not allow wake timers to wake up the machine). My batch file to sleep is 1 simple line:

```
PsShutdown -d -t 2
```

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: This didn't work in my pc...

Answer (score 2):

.NET to the rescue. This solution put computer to sleep without need of changing PC config (turning off hibernation).
Run this command in batch:

`powershell.exe -command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::SetSuspendState([System.Windows.Forms.PowerState]::Suspend, $false, $false)"`

You can use either `::Suspend` for sleep, or `::Hibernate` (which the way the other answers work). [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library) for SetSuspendState.

As `System.Windows.Forms` namespace is not loaded by default (it does in Powershell ISE), you need to load assembly for that at first.

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20713783/1908192)

Answer (score 0):

You may try SetSystemPowerState to avoid having to disable Hiberanate.

rundll32.exe kernel32.dll,SetSystemPowerState

Note that adding 1,0 or 1 0 or even doing Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0 0 1 or Rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,0,1 that the arguments (0,0,1) mean NOTHING.

The powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState does not parse rundll32 style arguments and thus ignores them.  That is why you have to disable hibernate.

Comment: This is useful for Windows XP, not Vista or later.

Comment: Note that rundll32 ignores the arguments you give it (hence why SetSuspendState always hibernates) since the DLL isn't designed to accept arguments from rundll32.

Comment: -1: This is outright wrong. It doesn't work under the OP's desired operating system.

Comment: rundll32 is NOT passing the arguments hence why you have to disable Hibernate to make it work.  The default args tell it to always hibernate, but if hibernate is disabled the DLL API defaults to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered.

powercfg -h off & start /min "" C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0 & ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 > nul & powercfg -h on & exit

See the following:

[What is the command to use to put your computer to sleep (not hibernate)?](https://superuser.com/questions/39584/what-is-the-command-to-use-to-put-your-computer-to-sleep-not-hibernate)

Comment: If you believe this question is a duplicate, feel free to flag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a batch file and insert the following lines:

```
7200 = 2 hours

@echo off
timeout /t 7200 /nobreak
powercfg -h off
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
powercfg -h on
```