# Is there anyway to enable autosleep in batch in windows 10?

Tags: windows, batch-file, sleep

I have a requirement that enable autosleep in batch file.
The reason is i want to `autosleep my computer after getting off work, but disable autosleep when i'm on duty`

- I know how to auto wake up my computer by using RTC in BIOS
- I know how to run a batch at certain time by using scheduler

The only thing I don't know is how to enable or disable autosleep by batch.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html and set the `standby-timeout-ac` value to x minutes (or 0 for never).

Comment: See also [Sleeping a computer via batch file in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/q/145400)

Comment: It's not dumplicated, what i want is to set autosleep time, not sleep the computer

Answer (score 1):

#### What I want is to set autosleep time

Use `powercfg`.

**Examples**

Set timeout to 5 minutes:

```
powercfg -x standby-timeout-ac 5
```

Set timeout to never:

```
powercfg -x standby-timeout-ac 0
```

---

#### Syntax

```
powercfg [Options]
```

...

```
-change setting value
-x setting value

Modify one of the following settings in the current power scheme:
          -monitor-timeout-ac minutes
          -monitor-timeout-dc minutes
          -disk-timeout-ac minutes
          -disk-timeout-dc minutes
          -standby-timeout-ac minutes
          -standby-timeout-dc minutes
          -hibernate-timeout-ac minutes
          -hibernate-timeout-dc minutes

Setting any value to 0 will set the timeout=Never

AC settings are used when the system is on AC power. 
DC settings on battery power.
```

Source [powercfg](http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [powercfg](http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html) - Control power settings, configure Hibernate/Standby modes.