# Hibernate computer with shortcut and delay

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I need a hibernate shortcut on the desktop of my computer.
I found a [tutorial](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/23836-hibernate-shortcut-create.html) which works good (code is below). The only problem is that I need to delay the hibernate.

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

The reason is because I use remote desktop to shut down, and if I don't disconnect the remote desktop first I have to wait for it to time out next time I want to connect.

So a delay of say 10 seconds should be good enough to be able to disconnect.

I found this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/83437/hibernate-computer-with-a-timeout-from-command-line-on-windows-7) but when I use that, it shuts down completly. I need to make the computer hibernate so that I can start it again with WOL.

Any ideas on how to delay the hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need to delay the hibernate.

You can use `timeout`for this.

Use the following batch file (and point your shortcut to the batch file):

```
@echo off
rem delay for 10 seconds
timeout 10 /nobreak
rem hibernate
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) - Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch file.

Comment: Flashy stuff with the count down :-) Thank you!