# How to schedule taskkill in bat file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, tasks, timeout

I want something like this:-

```
taskkill 7z.exe after 50sec.
code 1
code 2
code 3
```

7z.exe will be killed after 50 sec but the program should execute `code 1` `code 2` `code 3` without waiting for the taskkill. May be 7z.exe would be killed when `code 2` is being executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a batch file wait / sleep for some seconds?](http://superuser.com/questions/48231/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-wait-sleep-for-some-seconds)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but definitely helpful to link that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill 7z.exe after 50 seconds, you should use

```
start 7z.exe
timeout /t 50
taskkill /im 7z.exe
```

Put this in a batch file and use `start` to launch this process independently of the other (code1, code2, code3) stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If CPU usage is important, may want to use ping with a loopback address and a timeout, like so:

```
@echo off
:: Pause for approx. 50 seconds
PING -n 51 127.0.0.1>NUL 2>&1

:: Force kill 7-zip
taskkill /f /im 7z.exe
```