# Logitech Options + can it peacefully coexist with Options?

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

I have 2 mice, one (the MX Master) is outdated, the other (Anywhere 2S) is not.

The latest software (Options +) doesn't support the MX Master. I assume it is because MX Master can't do the logitech keyboard mouse sharing.

Can Options and Options plus coexist?

I use the 2S all the time anyhow as it is more nimble but occasionally, like if I forget to recharge the 2S, I use the MX Master. Without having any logitech software installed the MX Master is extremely clunky to move around, so it needs the options software.

Normally I would just keep using the options, I couldn't really care less about the new features in options +.

But options has had this bug forever where it stops working sometimes coming out of sleep. Then you have to go in and kill most of the running logitech tasks.. you can't just start the program again until you kill those first.

So it is very annoying. That's why I would like to use the new software. But I don't want to ditch the old software for the mx master.

Comment: Would it be worth setting up a batch file you can run on your desktop that simply kills the various logitech processes? https://superuser.com/questions/702622/how-to-schedule-taskkill-in-bat-file

Comment: yes I've been meaning to get around to that or a powershell script

Comment: however that would still be an annoying workaround, just less annoying than using taskmanager